# Friend keyword not accessing private fields

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

so I'm trying to overload a << operator for my class using friend keyword to access private fields. 
Code:

```
//Edge.h
#pragma once
class Edge
{
private:
    int startVertice;
    int endVertice;
    int weight;
public:
    //cut
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Edge*);
};

//Edge.cpp
//cut
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,const Edge *n) {
    out << "Start: [" << n->startVertice << "] End: [" << n->endVertice << "] Weight: [" << n->weight << "]";
    return out;
}
//cut
```

However IntelliSense tells me that `member Edge::startVertice is inaccessible`. Same for `endVertice` and `weight`. 
Where have I made a mistake? :D

EDIT: 
Compiler errors (connected to this case):

- syntax error, missing ";" before "&"
- ostream: 'friend' not allowefg on data declarations
- missing type specifier (int assumed)
- unexpected token preceding ';'
- 'ostream' is not a member of std

Comment: "_However IntelliSense tells me that_" Does your code compile? If it does - I don't see a problem. IntelliSense isn't perfect..

Comment: If you implement the function inside the class in Edge.h, does the IntelliSense business go away?

Comment: No it does not. That's why I'm asking. Compiler spits other errors as well

Comment: Works fine for me, no IntelliSense errors

Comment: What are the "other errors" that your compiler gives you? As mentioned while Intellisense may give some, in the end it's your compiler that has the last word.

Comment: @Wylfryd "_Compiler spits other errors as well_" So copy-paste the errors from the compiler (without paraphrasing), not from intelliSense.

Comment: An `#include <ostream>` at the top solved the problems for me (including intellisense).

Comment: Generally speaking, in `operator<<`, `const Edge *n` should be `const Edge &n`

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, it did. Thank you. Though I don't quite get why I should include it in header file too.

Comment: @Wylfryd Because you use `std::ostream` in your header file (in the declaration of the friend function). If you don't include `<ostream>` the compiler doesn't know what `std::ostream` is.

Comment: @Wylfryd not including <iostream> gives a bunch of errors and `inaccesible` is far far down the list of them, why would you bring that one up and not tell about the rest?

Comment: @Wylfryd - If the `ostream` is not known in the header, the friend declaration doesn't work. That's what confuses intellisense.

Comment: @Borgleader Thank you!

Comment: @Wylfryd Because you use `std::ostream`. Without looking in that header, the compiler has no idea what `std::ostream` is supposed to be.  If you really want (and you're sure you don't need the full version), you might use `#include <iosfwd>` in the header instead, which says that `ostream` is a type but does not include the class definition.